# Iterating through numbers where order doesn't matter [java]

Tags: java, loops, modularity

What do I mean by order doesn't matter?

When searching through numbers with a regular for loop, we will come across numbers that "repeat" such as "1135" "1315" or "5113"

---

A good example of this would be sum of digits of a number where each digit **x** has a function **f(x)** applied to it.

Assuming upto 4 digit numbers with x^5 [just so there isn't overlap between adjacent values] rather than searching like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<9999; i++)
    return i;
```

we could search numbers like this:

```
0003    0123
0013    1123
0113    0223
1113    1223 
0023    2223....
```

to get

```
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<=i; j++)
    for (int k=0; k<=j; k++)
    for (int l=0; l<=k; l++)
        return i*1000+j*100+k*10+l; //returns 4 digit number ijkl
```

Which drastically reduces the search size to <800 vs 9999 as before.

this works alright, but the code has to be manually altered when we're dealing with higher digit numbers.

---

**So these are my 3 questions:**

Can this code be altered for **modularity**?

Is there a **more efficient** way to iterate through such numbers?

Bonus points : Is there a different way to iterate through when **there is an overlap**?

eg: 1111 == 0002 when f(x) = x!

Comment: The question is still a bit unclear, at least to me. Can you add some concrete sample input and the output you're trying to get for it?

Comment: I can do this, but I don't understand what you mean by "concrete input"?

Comment: An actual example. E.g., "for the input of 123 I want to get 987"

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. I'm not sure if I can word it that way, but I've edited the question to [hopefully] make it more clear as to what I'm looking for. Is this better?

Comment: To get the effect of a variable number of nested for loops use recursion.